# Links is it possible to show alternate text when the pdf is printed?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, urls, printing, ocg

I want to have an electronic pdf version that says:

> See the game [Guillotine (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO8zUJ-suCE&feature=youtu.be&t=26s).

But in the printed version it should just say:

> See the game Guillotine.

Is this type of behavior possible? I know about the `\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}` option, but changing the color isn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

`hyperref`'s `ocgcolorlinks` option breaks any other OCG (PDF Layer) making package (`ocg-p`, `ocgx`), but the closing period and the string "(video)." must be placed on printable/non-printable OCGs on their own in order to meet the requested behaviour.

Pkg `ocgx2` re-implements `ocgcolorlinks`, while allowing the addition of more OCGs using the `ocg` environment.

Since layers for printing and viewing (`OCPrint`, `OCView`) are automatically created when loading `ocgx2` with the `ocgcolorlinks` option, they can be re-opened and used for the closing period and the "(video)." string. (Requires version 0.29 [2017/06/08] of `ocgx2`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[urlcolor=red]{hyperref}

%`ocg' environment (PDF Layers); line/page breakable ocgcolorlinks
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}[2017/06/08]

\begin{document}\Huge

See the game \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO8zUJ-suCE&feature=youtu.be&t=26s}{%
  Guillotine\ocglinkprotect{\begin{ocg}{}{OCPrint}{off}\makebox[0pt][l]{.}\end{ocg}}
            \ocglinkprotect{\begin{ocg}{}{OCView}{on}(video).\end{ocg}}%
}

\end{document}
```

Note that OCG visibility setting for printing is honoured only by Acrobat Reader, a few other non-free viewers and the Chrome/Chromium PDF browser plugin.